# Is the product topology the most finest topology you can give to the cartesian product and why?

Tags: general-topology

I was reading about box and product topology which are given to Cartesian products . I want to know that is the product topology(excluding the box topology) the finest topology that I can give to a certain Cartesian product.

I also have this feeling that box and product topology are the only topologies are the only topologies I can give to a Cartesian product.(Then my first question has an obvious answer). If that is the case then why can we only give two topologies . Why cant we give more topologies to the cartesian product

Comment: You could give it the discrete or indiscrete topology.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "can give" under certain conditions? E.g. of the projections being continuous?

Comment: I mean that is the topology generated by the basis $S_\beta = \{{\pi_\beta}^-1(U_\beta)|U_\beta \text{open in} X_\beta\}$ the most finest topology when compared to all other topologies . Yes I mean the projections being continuous@joriki

Comment: Then any topology that is finer than the product topology would do. If you want uniqueness, you need to appeal to a universal property.

Comment: I told you yesterday that the powerset is, as @DavidMitra mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the product topology is the *coarsest* topology for which all the projections on its coordinates are continuous.

In general, we may define topologies on a cartesian product that have "nothing to do" with the initial topologies on its coordinates. The following demonstrates that underlying sets tell us nothing (besides their cardinality) about the topologies that may live on them:

Given a topological space $(X, \tau)$ and any bijection $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ we may define a topology $\tau_*$ on $Y$ by setting
$$
V \in \tau_* \text{ iff } f^{-1"}V \in \tau
$$
for all $V \subseteq Y$.

Then $f \colon (X, \tau) \rightarrow (Y, \tau*)$ is a homeomorphism, so $\tau$ and $\tau_*$ "are essentially the same topology living on different sets".

Comment: Which I also told you yesterday @OP